# I cannot get past "collecting 'whatever package name' " on ANY python package I am trying to install

Tags: python, pip, telethon

I cannot get past "collecting 'whatever package name' " on any python package I am trying to install..

I have installed python 3.5 with pip 7.1.2

This is what I have tried..

`pip install telethon`
and..
`python -m pip install telethon`

Just stops on Collecting Telethon.. No downloading after that..

Then I tried: `pip -vvv install -U telethon --user`

Results are:

```
C:\Users\ACER>pip -vvv install -U telethon --user
Collecting telethon
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/telethon/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org

C:\Users\ACER>
```

I tried:
`pip install scrapy`
`python -m pip install scrapy`

Same thing!! Just stops at collecting scrapy.. No downloading after that..

I have downloaded the tarball files: pip install scrapy-master.tar.gz & pip install Telethon-1.16.0.tar.gz
full of errors when tring to install them locally..

All above is from CMD.. Then I have tried to install them directly from the repository via PyCharm. I get..

```
Failed to install package 'telethon'
Executed command:
pip install --user --index-url https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/ telethon==1.16.0
Error occured:
Non-zero exit code (-1073741819)

Proposed solution:
Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe'.

Command output:
Collecting telethon==1.16.0
```

I do not know whatelse to do to get basically ANY python package to install after "collecting 'whatever package name'"
However I am really tring to get Telethon installed..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Try using an elevated command prompt with administrator privileges.

Comment: Yes I tried that no change

Comment: Update your `pip` version, 7.1.2 is way too old. Download [`pip-20.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/b1/56a834acdbe23b486dea16aaf4c27ed28eb292695b90d01dff96c96597de/pip-20.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl) and install via `pip install --upgrade path\to\pip-20.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding

```
--no-cache-dir
```

while you are installing.

Hope that works.

```
pip install telethon --no-cache-dir
```

Check [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching) for more info.

Comment: Hi I tried that and I am getting the same thing: 
C:\Users\ACER>pip install telethon --no-cache-dir
Collecting telethon

C:\Users\ACER>

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Did you check the link to the site?

Comment: Yes I did.. Since I cannot install ANY python package it might be on my side.. However everything is installed meaning Python 3.5 and PIP 7.1.2.. With the right PATH

Comment: I upgraded Python to Version 3.8.. Everything working fine now :D

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded Python to Version 3.8.. Everything working fine now :D

Comment: That's great to hear.